# Naphthalene absorbed by HDPE?

Tags: plastics

I placed some empty HDPE plastic vitamin bottles in a sealed closet
with moth balls, (naphthalene, d-diclorobenzne.) Years later I found
the mothball smell had somehow gotten *into* the bottles, and no amount
of airing them out would get rid of it. I assume the
naphthalene etc. has actually been absorbed by the HDPE itself and is there
to stay, no?

Come to think about it, it all makes sense: when deploying mothballs one can simply toss their plastic packages into the closet, not bothering to tear open their wrappers. The smell gets out of the bag and into the closet just about the same as if one tore them open.

Comment: As it had years to come in the HDPE, it would have years to come out. There is also the question why to store vitamines for years, unless just being empty bottles.

Comment: Yes, and now the bottles are useless for storing vitamins, spices, etc. Even for storing mothballs themselves, as we now see while water cannot pass through their walls, naphthalene can!

Comment: PE is famous for absorbing smells. In communist era, when original bottles for bicycles were not easy to get, my colleage and me often used some empty PE bottles. (PETS were not common yet at all).  After months, they got all various smells one cannot get rid of, so then had to be replaced.

Comment: @Poutnik. Please explain your experiment with plastic bottle in the communist regime. For exemple, what is  a "bottle for bicycles" ?  Were they in or not in PE ? Why did you replace them by PE bottles ? Were PE bottles easier to find ? Were they used for doing chemistry experiments ? Or for keeping beverages for a long time ? What sort of beverages ? Did you find differences in behavior if you compared PE bottles and the other bottles ?

Comment: @Maurice It is rare one simple comment brings so many questions.. :-)  // It was not an experiement, rather practical necessity due availability. I assume bottles placed in bicycle holders are, at least mostly, PE/PP, the replacements may be just of different qualities. I also assume all these bottles capture smells in long term, especially if not cleaned properly, being nonpolar and absorbing nonpolar/little polar molecules of smalls. PET as more polar plastic is far less vulnerable to catch smells.

Comment: BTW, polyethylene also absorbs some natural pigments well. Store tomato products in a polythene container and lycopene will permanently permeate into and stain the plastic. Some plant pigments are also quite stable: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0031018288900612

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Or carotens from carrots.